# How to make css file to include in email template magento 2.3.3

Tags: magento2, email-templates

I want to write certain css for my email templates.
How can i do that.
Please tell me how should i make a custom css file for email templates and include it in my email template content https://prnt.sc/10ov9rl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't need to create CSS. You just add your style in the _email.less file which located below path.

> app/design/frontend/{{YOUR THEME NAME
> HERE}}/default/web/css/source/_email.less

After that, you have to run commands.

**Note:** Whenever you change anything into the _email.less file you have to run the commands.

Let me know if you still facing any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Use this way to call css file in email template

Vendor_Module::css/filename.css

```
{{css file="Magento_Sales::css/filename.css"}}
```

Comment: Have you tried this? How can i call the css file which is thr in my custom theme?

Answer (score 0):

Please check this out

https://nwdthemes.com/2018/05/25/how-to-style-email-templates-in-magento-2/

I hope this might help you

Thanks

Comment: Already referred this. But did not understand anything